# Como receber dados de entrada em C até não ter mais entrada?

Tags: c

O negócio é o seguinte:

Como receber entradas em C (inteiros) até que "ENTER" seja pressionado?

No meu programa, o usuário deverá entrar com uma lista encadeada no seguinte formato:

num0 num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 .. numN.

Ex. de lista:

19 8 9 14 15 9 -9 0 7 6 5 4 -123 1.

O tamanho da lista é desconhecido. Ele poderá ser de quantos inteiros o usuário desejar digitar.

Como parar a entrada após o útilmo número ser digitado?

O que eu preciso é que após o enter ser pressionado, o programa para de ler as entradas.

Ex. O usuário digita: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 e agora [ENTER]. Como ler a lista, visto que não uso nenhuma condição para parar a entrada?

O programa deve aceitar números inteiros negativos, não-negativos e zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir um ponto para encerrar a leitura, no caso o fim é a quebra de linha ***ENTER***.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char c = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    while(c != '\n'){
        scanf("%d%c", &n, &c);
        sum += n;
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

O que acontece aqui?

O `scanf` pega os valores direto do `stdin`, que é a entrado de valores, e o `stdin` tem as mesmas propriedades de um arquivo (tem um valor reservado para ele).

Assim como a leitura de um arquivo, quando se lê os valores de `stdin`, a linguagem vai percorrendo até chegar ao fim da inserção, mas como definir o fim da inserção?

Perceba que no `scanf` tem o seguinte formato *"%d%c"*, quando o usuário digitar um número, ele recolhe o número e recolhe o próximo carácter inserido.

Quando o carácter posterior ao número for uma quebra de linha ou quando você bater o enter, `c` será igual a `'\n'`, fazendo assim com que o *While* encerre e todas as somas sejam adicionadas a sua variável.

Quando a entrada é feita através de arquivos, o `scanf` pode identificar a ultima informação através tendo um retorno menor que 1.

Ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char c = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    while(scanf("%d",&n) > 0){
        sum += n;
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta, pois, do modo que você me ensinou, estou tendo problemas. Acho que agora fui mais claro.

Comment: @L.Pedro, você deve problema com que tipo de entrada? eu fiz o teste com quantos números quis, positivos, negativos e zeros, não deu nenhum erro, mas talvez vc deva procurar por sinais, quem sabe isso possa te ajudar

Comment: Na verdade, está funcionando. No meu programa, após receber as entradas, eu inverto a lista e a imprimo invertida; Contudo, esse programa faz parte de um problema que estou resolvendo em um site no qual você resolve problemas de lógica e submete o seu código fonte a uma avaliação. No meu computador ele está funcionando, mas no servidor desse site, quando eles executam, gera um erro de execução. Vou dar como resolvido, pois o problema pode estar em outro lugar. Muito obrigado. Detalhe: O sistema deles fala que gerou um erro, mas não mostra qual.

Comment: @L.Pedro, então... isso não iria funcionar nunca, pois a entrada feita por sites com exercícios de lógica, usam entradas através de arquivos, e isso tem uma diferença na hora de programar, eu acrescentei mais coisas na resposta. Quando for fazer a pergunta, dizer finalidade e/ou onde o código irá rodar, ajuda muito por causa dassas variações.

Answer (score 2):

Sem um contexto não dá para oferecer a melhor solução, considerando que todos os itens serão inseridos e finalizados com um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> e apenas quando tiver um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> sem digitar mais nada é que deve encerrar, uma das soluções possíveis pode ser essa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (1) {
        int num = -1;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num >= 0) sum += num;
        else break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h7ZOeZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/helhzrsj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopUntilData.c).

Se puder aceitar números negativos essa solução não funciona, mas a pergunta deu margem. Nesse caso complicaria bastante e talvez o `scanf()` nem seja a melhor solução, a não ser que use algum truque.

Comment: Eu não falei, mas eu terei de usar números negativos também. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @L.Pedro faltam outros detalhes para dar uma resposta mais adequada, pra falar a verdade talvez essa pergunta deveria ser fechada como não clara, mesmo dizendo isso, ainda é complicado dar uma resposta que atenda exatamente o que quer, sem ter que adivinhar.

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: O problema é que já existem 3 respostas para a original, então é tarde demais, se nenhuma resposta foi útil então acho que a pergunta deva ser fechada por não estar clara e e criar uma nova. De qualquer forma precisa fazer melhor que isso, ainda está confuso e como indica ser um problema bem mais complicado precisa postar na nova pergunta o que já fez e qual o problema que está enfrentando para ter uma pergunta específica. A forma atual a pergunta não funciona aqui já que você está pedindo para fazer tudo para você e não é algo tão trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (scanf("%d",&num) != EOF) {
sum += num;
}
```

Para encerrar a entrada digite CTRL-D.